# awk print tab delimited columns with find execdir

Tags: awk, find, exec

I am trying to print out columns that are separated by tabs.

First, I use `find` command to identify a list of files to process.

Second, I parse the file path to generate the filename to be used for output later using `split`.

Third, I print out a few columns that I needed (including the first column is combined from a few columns with underscore) in the tab-delimited format specified using `-v OFS='\t'`.

Forth, I print out the output path and the file name ended with `_step3`.

```
INPUT="/Users/dir/in"
OUTPUT="/Users/dir/out/"
find "$INPUT" -type f -iname "*.txt_cap.txt" -execdir awk -v OFS='\t' var="$OUTPUT" '{n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print ($1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$3, $2, $5, $6, $7) >> (var p[n] "_step3")}' {} +
```

I got the following error message. What went wrong?

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

UPDATE - based on the suggestion from @glennjackman after adding -v for each variable, there is a different error message.

```
INPUT="/Users/dir/in"
OUTPUT="/Users/dir/out/"
find "$INPUT" -type f -iname "*.txt_cap.txt" -execdir awk -v OFS='\t' -v var="$OUTPUT" '{n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print ($1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$3, $2, $5, $6, $7) >> (var p[n] "_step3")}' {} +
```

I got the following error message:

```
awk: can't open file MAP_pv1.txt_cap.txt
 source line number 1
```

A side question, when I use `find "$INPUT" -type f -iname "*.txt_cap.txt"` I could see a list of files shown on the terminal. I was also able to see the files displayed when using `"$INPUT" -type f -iname "*.txt_cap.txt"`. But when combined with awk, the first one with longer file matching pattern, I was able to get error messages for the command, but there was no error messages and no output files generated when just `.txt` used as matching pattern. Does anyone know the reason for the silence behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the main question? You only seem to have the side question there. And, about the side question, what are the actual commands you are running? What is it that shows results and what does not? Awk's results will depend on the contents of your files. Can you give us an example we can reproduce? Finally, your quoting in the awk command is strange. Is that really what you use? `"$2, "` will print `$2, ` and not the second field. Please [edit] your question, clarify what you want to ask and show us an example we can test.

Comment: Thanks. @terdon, after drafted the question, I forgot to put down the error message I got. Very embarrassed!

Comment: Yes, wrong quoting in `print ($1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$3, "$2, "$5, "$6, "$7)`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for spotting the mistake. I fixed it and still see the same error message. I don't know if there's something wrong with specifying`-v OFS` and `-v var` using the same `-v`.

Comment: I missed that. You absolutely need to use `-v` **for each** variable

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks. I updated the post. Now getting another error message. I took the `-v var="$OUTPUT"` part out of the command and just run `find "$INPUT" -type f -iname "*.txt_cap.txt" -exec awk -v OFS='\t' '{n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print ($1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$3, $2, $5, $6, $7) >> (p[n] "_step3")}' {} +` I was able to generate the files I need, except they are not in the directory I want them to be.

Comment: Since you're using `-execdir` rather than `-exec`, the leading component of `FILENAME` will always be simply `./` I think; so you don't actually need to remove anything before prepending the new target directory (it will look like `/Users/dir/out/./MAP_pv1.txt_cap.txt` but the extra `./` in the middle should not be a problem AFAIK)